# iOS Safari Adds Additional Border On Background Image

Tags: html, ios, css, google-chrome, safari

> ### HTML CODE

```
<div class="pageHeader">
<span class="coolStyleUnderline">Change Password</span>
</div>
```

> ### CSS CODE

```
.pageHeader {
   text-align: center;
   color: #750000;
   font-family: "MedievalSharp";
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 60px;
}
.coolStyleUnderline {
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black, #750000);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
   border-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, #750000);
   border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #750000, black);
   border-image-slice: 1;
   display: inline-block;
   line-height: .9;
   border-bottom: 6px solid #750000;
}
```

> ### Things I have tried

- Setting the padding to 0
- Setting appearance (including webkit, etc.) to "none"
- Setting the line-height to 1
- Setting the border to none BEFORE the border-bottom attribute

> ### Devices With Issue

- iPad Pro 12.9in (Safari and Chrome)
- iPhone X (Safari and Chrome)
- iPhone 6s (Safari and Chrome)

I have attached two photos. The first one is what the border is supposed to look like (taken on Windows Chrome) and the second one is what I am getting on my apple devices. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

[No Issue Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V857J.png)

[Issue Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGLAw.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out boys. All I had to do was specify the border image width. This was done by adding the following to .coolStyleUnderline :

```
border-image-width: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
```

Thank you to everyone that tried! Have a great day!